# "print x," equivalent in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

Basically, I want to print out a string of values in a single line, in Python2 a statement like this one would suffice:

```
print x,
```

How to write the same simple statement in Python3 (i.e., without using any special formatting) ?

Comment: Wassim, why did you post this here instead of Stack Overflow? You are a member there, and pretty active.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: your question is surprising! I don't know, I just posted it here. Could you please tell me why I had to post it in SO?

Comment: Well, it's an implementation question, not a conceptual one. "Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting expert answers on **conceptual questions** about software development." - from the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: Thanks for the enlightening answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> print(1, end=' '); print(2)
1 2
```

For further enlightenment:

```
>>> help(print)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an explanation from the following site:

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

See the section called "Print Is A Function."

> Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
>
> New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.x you would say:

```
print(x, end='')
```

Not sure what you mean by 'special formatting'.

Comment: By "not using any special formatting" I meant using the simplest and direct equivalent to the Python2 version of the statement without applying any kind of string manipulation. Thanks for the answer.