# I need to make the output be in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I already have the code to get all the words with digits in them out of the text, now all I need to do is to have the text all in one line.

```
with open("lolpa.txt") as f:
    for word in f.readline().split():
        digits = [c for c in word if c.isdigit()]
        if not digits:
            print(word)
```

The split makes the words all be in a different column.
If I take out the `.split()`, it types in the words without the digits, literally just takes the digits out of the words, and makes every letter to be in a different column.

**EDIT**: Yes, `print(word,end=" ")` works, thanks. But I also want the script to now read only one line. It can't read anything that is on line 2 or 3 etc.

The second problem is that the script reads only the FIRST line. So if the input in the first line would be

```
i li4ke l0ke like p0tatoes potatoes
300 bla-bla-bla 00bla-bla-0211
```

the output would be

```
i like potatoes
```

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8914173/24718

Comment: what's the input and what's your expected output?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The input is "i li4ke l0ke like p0tatoes potatoes" and in the next line "300 bla-bla-bla 00bla-bla-0211". The problem is the second line is not showing.

Comment: @Kichrootra you're using `for word in f.readline().split():` which means it'll only loopover the first line in f.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python v 3.x you'd use

```
print(word, end='')
```

to avoid the newline.

in Python v 2.x

```
print word,
```

you'd use the comma at the end of the items you are printing. Note that unlike in v3 you'd get *a single blank space* between consecutive prints

Note that `print(word),` won't prevent a newline in v 3.x.

--

***Update** based on edit in original post re code problem:*

With input:

```
i li4ke l0ke like p0tatoes potatoes
300 bla-bla-bla 00bla-bla-0211
```

this code:

```
def hasDigit(w):
   for c in w:
      if c.isdigit():
         return True
   return False

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        digits = [w for w in line.split() if not hasDigit(w)]
        if digits:
            print ' '.join(digits)
#   break  # uncomment the "break" if you ONLY want to process the first line
```

will yield all the "words" that do not contain digits:

```
i like potatoes
bla-bla-bla    <-- this line won't show if the "break" is uncommented above
```

*Note*:

The post was a bit unclear if you wanted to process *only* the first line of the file, **or** if the problem was that your script *only* processed the first line. This solution can work either way depending on whether the `break` statement is commented out or not.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if I'm getting annoying, but how do I enable multiple lines?

Comment: @Kichrootra I am not sure I understand your question (also, what version of Python are you using?)

Comment: I am using Python 3.2.
The problem is that the script only works with 1 line, and that means if I skip a line in the text, it won't show it.

Comment: Let's say, I my text is

i lik3 like p0tatoes potatoes. #yes, it will work and show only the words without nubmers



the3y they a4e are ta5ty tasty #and here, since I skipped a line, it won't work. it will only show the first line.

Comment: I think you will also need to do a `.strip()` to strip the ending CR from the file, no?

Comment: @Kichrootra See my updated answer with a code solution. I also print `bla-bla-bla` since it doesn't contain any digits. Let me know if this does what you wanted.

Comment: @Levon Thank you! You don't even know how much you helped me, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Kichrootra Just curious, did you want to only process the first line or was it the other way around?

Comment: @Levon I did, earlier. But then the task changed, so I needed help making python read the whole file, not only the first line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3.x, you can do:

```
 print (word,end="")
```

to suppress the newline -- python 2.x uses the somewhat strange syntax:

```
 print word,  #trailing comma
```

Alternatively, use `sys.stdout.write(str(word))`.  (this works for both python 2.x and 3.x).

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("lolpa.txt") as f:
    for word in f.readline().split():
        digits = [c for c in word if c.isdigit()]
        if not digits:
            print word,
    print
```

Not `,` at the end of `print`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join()`:

```
with open("lolpa.txt") as f:
    print ' '.join(str(x.split()) for x in f if not [c for c in x.split() if c.isdigit()])
```

using a simple for loop:

```
import sys
with open("data.txt") as f: 
    for x in f:                #loop over f not f.readline()
        word=x.split()
        digits = [c for c in word if c.isdigit()]
        if not digits:
            sys.stdout.write(str(word))  #from mgilson's solution
```